# Custom TextView Error

Tags: android

I created a Class myTextView That's extends the TextView when i try to create an object for the same class :
Dynamically it works : myTextView mytv = new myTextView(this.MainActivity); It works.
but 
myTextView mtv = (myTextView)findViewById(R.id.mytV);

It gives an error. Refer the Log Cat Output.
Even if i change tag in xml from TextView to  it ain't works.
I'm new to android. Pls. Help.
code:

```
package com.example.exttest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    myTextView mtv  =   null;
    RelativeLayout rtv  =   null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rtv =   (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.parent);
        mtv =   new myTextView(getApplicationContext());
        mtv.setText("Hey Bub");
        mtv =   (myTextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        //rtv.addView(mtv);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
   android:id="@+id/parent" >

  <com.example.exttest.myTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Custom Text View"
        android:id="@+id/text1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

LogCat:

06-05 18:41:13.611: E/AndroidRuntime(24106): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 18:41:13.611: E/AndroidRuntime(24106): Process: com.example.exttest, PID: 24106
06-05 18:41:13.611: E/AndroidRuntime(24106): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.exttest/com.example.exttest.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to com.example.exttest.myTextView
06-05 18:41:13.611: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
06-05 18:41:13.611: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-05 18:41:13.611: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-05 18:41:13.611: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-05 18:41:13.611: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-05 18:41:13.611: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-05 18:41:13.611: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-05 18:41:13.611: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 18:41:13.611: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-05 18:41:13.611: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-05 18:41:13.611: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-05 18:41:13.611: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 18:41:13.611: E/AndroidRuntime(24106): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to com.example.exttest.myTextView
06-05 18:41:13.611: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at com.example.exttest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
06-05 18:41:13.611: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-05 18:41:13.611: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-05 18:41:13.611: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-05 18:41:13.611: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    ... 11 more
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201): Process: com.example.exttest, PID: 24201
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.exttest/com.example.exttest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.example.exttest.myTextView
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.example.exttest.myTextView
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:603)
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201):    at com.example.exttest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201):    ... 11 more
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:  [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:446)
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:568)
06-05 18:42:53.619: E/AndroidRuntime(24201):    ... 22 more
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539): Process: com.example.exttest, PID: 24539
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.exttest/com.example.exttest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.example.exttest.myTextView
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.example.exttest.myTextView
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:603)
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539):    at com.example.exttest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539):    ... 11 more
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:  [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:446)
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:568)
06-05 18:54:41.590: E/AndroidRuntime(24539):    ... 22 more

Answer (score 0):

```
your code should look like this 
        mtv =   (myTextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        mtv.setText("Hey Bub");
remove this line  mtv =   new myTextView(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: bub i wrote that to show dynamically the line works. and the findViewbyId ain't remove the line new myTextView(getApplicationContext());

Comment: there is no need to create the object of myTextView you can get it from your xml as above two lines does and if you want to show dynamically thenn just take the reference of mtv. so no need of new myTextView(getApplicationContext());